# How to yield one array element and keep other elements in pyspark DataFrame?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame like:

```
+------------------------+
|                     ids|
+------------------------+
|[101826, 101827, 101576]|
+------------------------+
```

and I want explode this dataframe like:

```
+------------------------+
|     id|             ids|
+------------------------+
|101826 |[101827, 101576]|
|101827 |[101826, 101576]|
|101576 |[101826, 101827]|
+------------------------+
```

How can I do using pyspark udf or other methods?

Comment: Do you always have 3 elements?

Comment: yes, all elements have same length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way out is to copy `id` into `ids`. Explode `id` and use `array except` to exclude each id in the row. Code below.

```
 (
  df1.withColumn('ids', col('id'))
 .withColumn('id',explode('id'))
    .withColumn('ids',array_except(col('ids'), array('id')))

).show(truncate=False)

+------+----------------+
|id    |ids             |
+------+----------------+
|101826|[101827, 101576]|
|101827|[101826, 101576]|
|101576|[101826, 101827]|
+------+----------------+
```